# Unnatural GHDL behavior of type conversion between std_logic_vector and unsigned in association list

Tags: type-conversion, vhdl, hdl, ghdl

I have the following code that converts lower bits of unsigned into std_logic_vector in an association list. I can compile it and run simulation by using GHDL. But the output waveform has some unknown('U') bits in `inner_counter` though no unknown bit in `counter`. (The waveform image is following the code.) I think the bits of `inner_counter` and `counter` should have the save values. Does anyone know that this is an expected behavior or a bug of GHDL?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity test_bench is
end test_bench;

architecture default of test_bench is
  signal clk : std_logic := '0';
  signal counter : unsigned(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');

  component inner
    port (
    clk : in std_logic;
    inner_counter : in std_logic_vector(6 downto 0));
  end component;

begin

  i0 : inner port map (
  clk => clk,
  inner_counter => std_logic_vector(counter(6 downto 0)));

  process
  begin
    clk <= '1';
    wait for 1 ns;
    clk <= '0';
    wait for 1 ns;
  end process;

  process(clk)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      counter <= counter + 1;
    end if;
  end process;

end default;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity inner is
  port (
  clk : in std_logic;
 inner_counter : in std_logic_vector(6 downto 0));
end inner;

architecture default of inner is
begin
  --do something
end architecture;
```

[Waveform image of `counter` and `inner_counter`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjGkY.png)

Comment: Your waveform shouts "contention!" to me, ie I expect you're driving `inner_counter` from multiple places. But you have missed out that part of the code. Please could you edit your question to include the code for `entity inner`.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor if `inner_counter` of mode `in` was being driven from within `inner`, wouldn't that be a compiler error? Also note that the values are `'U'`, not `'X'` (not that I have a better answer!)

Comment: @scary_jeff  `inner_counter` must be being probed from within `entity inner` - there isn't a top-level `signal inner_counter`. With contention, you generally expect `'X'`s not `'U'`s, unless the contending signal were not being assigned to, in which case `'U'`s would be being driven, which trump anything else. We need to see inside inner.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor oh right, in ModelSim you can probe a port, so I assumed that was what we were seeing in that trace.

Comment: Your `inner` component has no output port, which would result in this component being synthesised away in actual hardware (as it effectively does nothing/would result in dangling logic). I mocked up a basic fix to this; Added an output port (and an intermediate register) and it simulates fine

Comment: @scary_jeff is likely correct. This appears to be an elaboration error in ghdl. A short term work around would be to use an intermediary signal.

Comment: See  ghdl issue [type converted actual in port map doesn't get actual's initial value #300](https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl/issues/300).

Comment: @MatthewTaylor Actually, there is nothing in the entity `inner`. As suggested by @gsm, this is just a implementation of "nothing". But this seems to be unnatural to me.

Comment: @user1155120 You are right. If I use an intermediate signal, it works as expected. And, thanks a lot for opening issue!

Comment: Tristan has commented on the issue report. It appears to be a GHW waveform dump issue. You could use either VCD or depending on the pedigree of your ghdl FST.